# DevExpress select all when clicked on GridView cell (TextEdit)

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I need to make it so when the user clicks on a cell with TextEdit in a grid view, it will select all in the textedit. I tried many many ways i could find in the internet, but none of them work well.

"EditorShowMode = MouseUp" way breaks everything, for example when you click on a cell that has checkedit; it selects the cell, then you need o click again to actually click on the CheckEdit.

["Use EditorShowMode = MouseUp and manually handle other things on MouseDown"](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18380/why-are-several-clicks-necessary-to-change-an-in-place-checkedit-s-state-when-multiple) is just ew. Won't work fine for all types of controls.

"Change selection length etc. on ShownEditor event" way doesn't work too, actually it selects the text when clicked, but it doesn't override the default function so the selection instantly changes. Also tried the SelectAll method but it had some problems that i dont remember (probably didnt work at all).

I have really tried many things, but couldn't find a totally fine way. Please tell me if *you can* get a working way without breaking other types of controls in the grid.

Comment: I would suggest using an attached boolean property for this. Have you considered it?

Comment: I don't know about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by Pavel on DevExpress Support (works great):

> The easiest way to achieve this is to use the GridView.ShownEditor event to subscribe to the active editor's MouseUp event. Then, select all text in the MouseUp event handler and detach this handler to avoid subsequent text selection.

```
private void GridView_ShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView view = sender as GridView;
    if (view.ActiveEditor is TextEdit)
        view.ActiveEditor.MouseUp += ActiveEditor_MouseUp;
}

private void ActiveEditor_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    BaseEdit edit = sender as BaseEdit;
    edit.MouseUp -= ActiveEditor_MouseUp;
    edit.SelectAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use GridView CustomRowCellEdit event and set an event of text editor such as Mouse Up. Setting the RepositoryItemTextEdit MouseUp event can be set as in the example.

Example:

```
private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RepositoryItem is DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemTextEdit)
    {
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemTextEdit rep = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemTextEdit();
        rep.ReadOnly = false;
        rep.MouseUp += rep_MouseUp;
        e.RepositoryItem = rep;
    }       

}
void rep_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit te = sender as DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit;
    te.SelectAll();
}
```

Comment: This actually works, but.. It doesn't let me to select a specific part of the text if i want, i mean it should only work when you first click the textedit. I tried to use "Enter" event with the same way, didn't do anything. Hmm..

Comment: Any idea? hm. .

Answer (score 0):

You should handle Enter event for TextEdit

```
private void myRepositoryItemTextEdit_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    var editor = (DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit)sender;  
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>  
    {  
        editor.SelectionStart = 0;  
        editor.SelectionLength = editor.Text.Length;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't do anything visual even if the event is called and changed the selection length.

Comment: It seems that BeginInvoke call in needed. I've updated the answer

Comment: Okay, but works bad. It selects until the character i clicked at. Also tried SelectAll, but that just starts from end of the text and selects until the character i clicked.